# Best practice of using async for json data

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to save data received as JSON in DB. But my method is unnecessarily time-consuming, so I write the question.

Here's my code:

```
const data = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'foo',
  items: [{
    name: 'foo-1'
  }, {
    name: 'foo-2'
  }]
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'bar',
  items: [{
    name: 'bar-1'
  }, {
    name: 'bar-2'
  }]
}]

const createUser = (data) => {
  console.log('start create user:', data)
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('create user: ', data.name)
      resolve(data.id);
    }, 2000);
  });
}

const createUserMeta = (id, name) => {
  console.log('start create user meta:', name)
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('create user meta: ', id, name)
      resolve(`set ${id}: ${name}`)
    }, 3000)
  })
}

// Logic
async function asyncCall() {
  const result = []
  console.log('calling')
  for (const i of data) {
    console.log(i)
    const usersId = await createUser(i)
    for (const item of i.items) {
      const fn2Return = await createUserMeta(usersId, item.name)
      result.push(fn2Return)
    }
  }
  console.log(result)
}

asyncCall();
```

result is:

```
calling
{ id: 1, name: 'foo', items: [ { name: 'foo-1' }, { name: 'foo-2' } ] }
start create user: { id: 1, name: 'foo', items: [ { name: 'foo-1' }, { name: 'foo-2' } ] }
// wait 2 sec
create user:  foo
start create user meta: foo-1
// wait 3 sec
create user meta:  1 foo-1
start create user meta: foo-2
// wait 3 sec
create user meta:  1 foo-2
{ id: 2, name: 'bar', items: [ { name: 'bar-1' }, { name: 'bar-2' } ] }
start create user: { id: 2, name: 'bar', items: [ { name: 'bar-1' }, { name: 'bar-2' } ] }
// wait 2 sec
create user:  bar
start create user meta: bar-1
// wait 3 sec
create user meta:  2 bar-1
start create user meta: bar-2
// wait 3 sec
create user meta:  2 bar-2
[ 'set 1: foo-1', 'set 1: foo-2', 'set 2: bar-1', 'set 2: bar-2' ]
```

createUserMeta should wait for createUser to exit before starting it. But there is no need to wait for data[0] to complete to save data[1]. How can I run them in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
async function createUser(data) {
  const pk = await insertUser(data.id, data.name);
  const result = await Promise.all(data.items.map(createUserMeta);
  return {pk, result};
}

async function asyncCall() {
  const result = await Promise.all(data.map(createUser));
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap creating the user and related metadata to a function such as

```
async function createUserAndMeta(user) {
  console.log(user);
  const usersId = await createUser(user);
  const result = [];
  for (const item of user.items) {
    const fn2Return = await createUserMeta(usersId, item.name);
    result.push(fn2Return);
  }
  return result;
}
```

and then use `map` to map all users to promises and `Promise.all()` to await on them:

```
async function asyncCall() {
  const results = await Promise.all(data.map(createUserAndMeta));
  const result = results.flat(); // flatten array of arrays
  console.log(result);
}
```

Do note that if you have a lot of `data`, this will cause all requests to be done in parallel (e.g. for 50 users, it'll try to make 50 parallel `createUser` calls). To limit the concurrency to e.g. 5 at a time, you may want to use e.g. the [`p-queue` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/p-queue).